# trigger a query when data in view changes

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to trigger query by itself when the top 10 data in the view changes ? Basically the view has data of top 10 users with highest points. I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What sort of query did you have in mind?

Comment: if the top 10 users change and new user enters .Just to notify user if he is in top 10 or not anymore.

Comment: if the user is already in 10 and notify has already been sent then no need to send again but if he not anymore and gets back in then he needs to be notified.

Comment: Does this have to happen instantly?

Comment: @DanBracuk yes it should, I am using GCM (Google CLoud Messaging) to send the message part after insert/update query is processed.But After 2 select statements of verifying data then updating previous top 10 user's id then updating the current top 10 user's id  and then checking for in-ARRAY statement to check if user already exists or just got added,if he is in top 10 then another insert query of new points is sent to that respective user along with notification.I would like to know if I can optimize this whole process or this is the right way to use leaderboards?

Answer (score 0):

On a fundamental level, the answer to the questIon would be "no, there isn't," because there is no data "in" a view, in MySQL.

Views are not materialized in MySQL, so, for most practical purposes, they are only "query aliases" or "virtual tables" and their data not exist until they are accessed, and does not exist after the query that accesses them finishes executing.